# find out that system is time-invariant or not

Tags: signal-processing, systems-theory

Is this system linear and time-invariant? 
$$y(t) = −3x(2t − 2) + x(t)$$
I found this that is not time-variant but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Time-invariant means a shift in time in the input leads to the same output, shifted the same amount in time. Let's see if this is the case:

output to the shifted input: $t=t-t_0$
 $$-3x(2(t-t_0)-2)+x(t-t_0)=-3x(2t-2t_0-2)+x(t-t_0)$$

shifted output: $y(t-t_0)$
$$-3x(2t-2-t_0)+x(t-t_0)$$

So it is time-variant (or equivaently it is not time-invariant)

Comment: @anonymous downvoter What is wrong?

Comment: One of you is find it is time variant one of you said is not

Comment: @Soulmaster Both answers say the system *is time-variant* or equivalently, it *is not time-invariant*. This is because the time shift in input does not lead to identical shift in output (as both answers assert).

Answer (score 2):

Define $(\Theta_Tx)(t) = x(t-T)$.

Let $(Lx)(t) =  -3 x(2t-2) +x(t)$.

The system if time invariant **iff** $\Theta_T  L = L  \Theta_T$ for all $T$.

$(\Theta_T  (L x))(t) = (Lx)(t-T) = -3 x(2t-2-2T) +x(t-T)$.

$(L (\Theta_T x))(t) = -3 (\Theta_T x)(2t-2) +(\Theta_T x)(t) = -3 x(2t-2-T)+x(t-T)$.

Hence if $x$ is not constant, we have some $s,T$ such that $x(s) \neq x(s+T)$,
in which case
$(\Theta_T  (L x))({s \over 2} + 1 +T) \neq (L (\Theta_T x))({s \over 2} + 1 +T)$.

Comment: What notation is that theta_T L? What does it mean.

Comment: It means $\Theta_T$ composed with $L$.